# B2C redirect after user journey is completed

Tags: azure, passwords, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using custom policies in my B2C tenant and found out that the "Forgot password?" link redirects to an error page (**AADB2C90118**). After researching on the Internet I found a [custom policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset) which allows me to embed the password reset inside the sign-up or sign-in policy.

This works like a charm, validating the email an changing the password as expected. The issue I have is that I want to redirect the user to the sign-in page after the reset password is completed successfully.

My goal would be to redirect the user to the sign in page so he/she is able to sing in whit the new credentials. Is there a way to reset the user journey or redirect the user to the sign in page using custom policies?

Here is the **Step** that check if the user has selected to change his/her password:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>isPasswordResetFlow</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>          
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountChangePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

And here is the **TechnicalProfile** to change the password:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountChangePasswordUsingObjectId">
      <DisplayName>Change password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />

      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a precondition in the journey based on whether the user did password reset,  to launch another claims provider selection, which offers the exact same as the initial sign in/up page logic.

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isPasswordResetFlow</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isPasswordResetFlow</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Without this, the sample will not setup the SM-AAD session, and subsequent policy calls or silent token calls will need a sign in anyway.

Comment: I've just added this new step to my journey and it redirects correctly to a basic sign in page (it stills contains the "Don't have an account? Sign up" which I would need to remove), after that, the user is able to sign in successfully with the new password. My question now would be, is it possible to redirect to the base sign in page with all the sign up, forgot password and identity providers instead of a the basic sign in?

Comment: I'm seeing this when I have two separate AAD B2C environments, and I'm signed in to both (i.e. qa.myb2c.mydomain.com and myb2c.mydomain.com), if I have active sessions for both, one stops working, I have to delete the session cookie from the other in order for it to work