# How to make user return on login page after sign-up in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, claims-based-identity

When a user is signing-up in the system, he is automatically redirected to our application as a signed in user. I would like that after the sign-up, he is redirected to the signing page. I want this behavior since users need to be approved by an admin before having access to the system. I use custom policies.

I tried to use the "SM-Noop" session manager but it is not working. There is my code:

```
<!--Local account sign-up page-->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_phoneExtension" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalcode" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

**Edit1:**
The solution seems to be to add orchestrationSteps. There is a link doing that but with a password reset: [www.stackoverflow.com/a/62878136](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/62878136)
In my case, it is not working since I can't add two CombinedSignInAndSignUp in the same userJourney so it crashes. Any other idea?

**Edit2:**
There is my policy for the SignUpSignIn:

```
 <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

Still trying to figure out what to put in Order="5" and so on in my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

Comment: You need to add additional steps to the UserJourney. Otherwise the B2C considers the signup to be complete. Removing the session will only matter for the next time the application sends the user to B2C. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878136/

Comment: @AlexAIT It is not working since I already have a CombinedSignInAndSignUp type step and them, they are doing a PasswordReset. Having two of these steps make it so I can't even have my login page and I get an error when I try to access it. Do you have any other idea or a code sample I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the configuration you can do:

**Claim Type (To Print the Message from B2C Side)**

```
<ClaimType Id="userMessage">
        <DisplayName></DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
```

**ClaimsTransformation**

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GetUserMessage" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
        <InputParameters>
            <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="[![Your Account has been successfully created. To continue click on the sign-in link below.][1]][1]" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userMessage" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Technical Profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-UserMessage">
      <DisplayName>After Registration</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <!--Demo: hide the continue and cancel buttons -->
        <Item Key="setting.showContinueButton">false</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetUserMessage" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userMessage" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!--Demo: Show the paragraph claim with the message to the user -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userMessage" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

User Journey:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_isApproved</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
         <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_isApproved</Value>
          <Value>True</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SendClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-UserMessage" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
    </OrchestrationSteps>
```

**Note**: Make Sure in the "**AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId**" you add the below claim:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
```

Also in the "**SelfAsserted-UserMessage**" Profile, in the content definition you can have **custom page** which will have the link of your Login Page. Below is the screenshot of how it appears by default.

[image]

Comment: Working great! But I have 3 issues:
1. When trying to sign in with a normal user, I'm always being redirected to the "Your account has been successfully...". How to keep the normal behaviour for sign-in and only have this page for sign-up?
2. I activated the continue button on this page and when I click on it, it lets me in the system even if not approved. When disabling it like you did, is their a security breach possible?
3. How can I add a "go to login" button on this page to bring the user to the normal sign-in page?

Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: I found the issue in your answer as why in login I'm being redirected to this page: In the precondition, where we verify is "extension_isApproved" is true, you need to put "True" and not "true" in the value field since it's case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for that !! I corrected in the code.

Continue button is being hidden from the B2C side so no-one can enable the button from client side.

For the 3rd issue, you can create one HTML page and add a link in the HTML and include the URL in the content definition. To know more how you can customize the page see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Comment: You are right, I tried changing the HTML to enable the button client side but I can't connect. For the HTML, you are right that this could be a solution, but in my case I have 4 different environments, using the same HTMLs in a Blob storage. This would mean I would need 4 time a copy of this HTML file for the redirect, each with a different link. I was wondering if there could be another way directly in the custom policy file? If not, I'll go with your solution.

Comment: Good to have separate HTML for each environment. 
This will also give you flexibility to modify the Page based on the environment.