# Azure AD B2C - Custom Policy "Session" is left in incorrect state after running the "Self-Served Password Reset"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

We have a Custom Policy that is based on the [SocialAndLocalAccounts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts) starter pack.

We have been adding support from `Home Realm Discovery` based on this sample [HomeRealmDiscovery-Modern](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern) to redirect users using third-party-providers to their correct sign-in page (IdP)

We have also added support for `Domain Hints` to entirely **skip** our sign-in page for users that sign-in via a third-party identity provider.

The policy makes use of the new released [Self-Served Password Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#self-service-password-reset-recommended) as per official docs.

**What's the issue?**

When the user goes through the "Self-Served Password Reset", the B2C session is left in a corrupted state. If the user is redirected back to B2C, the session is not picked up.

How can we say that? What is the use case?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1: User goes to the application which redirects the user to the B2C Sign-In page.

2: User enters local account email (Gmail) and on the next Screen clicks on "Forgot your password" link which is implemented using the Self-Served Password Reset.

3: User goes correctly through the password reset flow, and ultimately enters the "MFA" factor (SMS code).

4: User correctly gets redirected to the Application with an ID token, successful login.

6: User clicks a link to a **new/different** application using the same custom policy.

7: The new application redirects the user to B2C (same custom policy)

**Expected Result:** The user should have a valid B2C Session and should not be prompted to sign-in again, but instead redirected to the callback of the new application with a valid `id-token`.

**Actual Result:** The user is sent back to the new application with an error message in the callback URL, and because of the error redirected back to B2C to re-login.

**Error Message:**

```
AADB2C90051: No suitable claims providers were found. 
Correlation ID: c014004a-d2da-4000-83e5-6d648f9acccc 
Timestamp: 2021-06-16 07:17:16Z
```

**IMPORTANT:** If the user goes through the normal sign-in flow (no password reset), **everything works correctly**. The user can switch between different applications and B2C picks-up the session correctly, without throwing errors or prompting a new sign-in. SSO among the different apps works as intended.

Here is the full `TrustFrameworkExtention` file which contains all the logic and extends from the Base file of the starter pack:
[TrustFrameworkExtention.xml](https://github.com/AlbozDroid/b2c-hrd-domainhint-sample/blob/main/B2C_1A_HRD_MODERN_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS-Clean.xml)

Comment: The cause is because your IdP technical profile, which the session cookie is targeting, will be disabled due to `<Item Key="ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable">identityProviders</Item>`, and you are not passing a domain_hint in the second app to the SignInHRD policy, which means all IdPs are disabled as `identityProviders` will be null. And B2C cannot then SSO you through - `No suitable claims providers were found.`.  Try pass a domain_hint in the SSO request from App2 to confirm this theory.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT even when we execute simple login (without going through password reset) there are no domain hints sent, and everything works correctly. We don't send domain hints for local accounts.

Comment: can u check LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress -> IncludeSSO = true ?

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu that is set to `false` currently. I'll try this and let you know. Is there any documentation about this? How to know what's the correct setting. I've got includeInSSO=false in all TPs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @redAce not yet. Working on it with some help from the MS AAD B2C team and once we find the solution will post it in here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915001/azure-b2c-session-causing-unintended-flow/68163019#68163019 I don't have the exact same problem as you, but this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In `CreateidentityProvidersCollectionLogic` change `SM-Noop` to `SM-DOMAIN`.
2. In `SM-DOMAIN` add:

```xml
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviders" />
```

Comment: Same error:  AADB2C90051: No suitable claims providers were found.                                                                
Correlation ID: 377ed111-289c-4329-943c-b9c78304bc5a
Timestamp: 2021-06-17+21:40:27Z

Comment: Can you remove ` <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isFederatedAuthentication" />` from SM-AAD

Comment: Same issue:                                                                                               
AADB2C90051: No+suitable+claims+providers+were+found.
Correlation+ID: ae665d9e-91df-4a53-92a5-aa7f6c2e3e17
Timestamp:+2021-06-18+14:02:27Z